# Will Java8 Supports Spring , Azure OAuth2 Integration

Tags: azure, spring-security, oauth-2.0, java-8

i was looking which is the minimum Version of java required for Spring Security, Azure, OAuth2 Integration, as i am using Java8 in my current project and have a task for that

Did not tried anything will looking for any information if anyone tried or faced any issues

Answer (score 0):

Spring Security 6 (and Boot 3) require a minimum of Java 17. With Java 8, you have to limit to Spring Security 5 (Boot 2).

You don't have to use Azure integration, but if you do so, you'll have to check the compatibility with the Spring versions you use.